# SignalR webSockets for mobile clients apps

Tags: java, android, .net, websocket, signalr

We want to develop a new real-time service for both web and mobile users. I saw that signalR has a java client library, but it didn't update since 3 years ago.

Is it possible for mobile apps to use other web sockets library with SignalR? Is .net has a good alternative for SignalR? We are also want to use it under load balancer system and SignalR has a very good solution for that.

Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft itself might have forgotten the project, but the open source community has kept updating it if you check the network diagram, https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/network Find a suitable fork and you might even maintain your own. That's how open source works.

Answer (score 3):

I have created signalr client library for android for new SignalR .net core server.

[SignalR-.net-core-android-client](https://github.com/Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client)

Note, that you can't use this library in Asp.net signalr, it for .net core signalR server.

And this is a server part by Microsoft, signalR server for .net core.

[SignalR .net core server](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR)